# Http post from another URL into an Angular 6 app

Tags: angular

There's a form on another URL e.g. abc.com/form.php

In there, it's a few variables that then posts into def.com/connect

def.com/connect is an angular6 app which has a route /connect configured to a component called ConnectComponent

How do I get the posted variables from the other domain? The error I'm getting when I was testing using PostMan is

Cannot POST /connect

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, use GET instead of POST.

```
<form action="def.com/connect" method="GET">
</form>
```

Now you can access posted data as url parameters (`ActivatedRoute` params).

If your data is sensitive and shouldn't be in the url, post the form to the php backend. In backend, store the data, and redirect to the angular url, with references to the stored data so that angular app can later access data through http requests.

Comment: How about for Http POST? I can get from the GET method but was wondering whether other methods work?

Comment: @JDYLE angular url is usually a static page. You cannot POST to this URL.